# How can I import objects from another file that I uploaded to Pythonanywhere.com?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, pythonanywhere

I'm new to Python. I uploaded three files (ending '.py') to pythonanywhere.com. In one of them I import objects from the other two. Everything worked perfectly on my computer, but ever since I uploaded the file to pythonanywhere.com I get the same mistake:

> Error running WSGI application 2022-08-05 19:12:17,368: NameError:
> name '{imported_object}' is not defined 2022-08-05 19:12:17,368:   File
> "/var/www/{my_name}_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 112, in 
> 2022-08-05 19:12:17,369:     from main import app as application  #
> noqa

It seems that the systems doesn't know where to look for the other two files even though all the three files are saved in the same directory.

UPD. Relevant part from the WSGI file:

```
`# +++++++++++ FLASK +++++++++++
# Flask works like any other WSGI-compatible framework, we just need
# to import the application.  Often Flask apps are called "app" so we
# may need to rename it during the import:
#
#
import sys
#
## The "/home/{my_name}" below specifies your home
## directory -- the rest should be the directory you uploaded your Flask
## code to underneath the home directory.  So if you just ran
## "git clone git@github.com/myusername/myproject.git"
## ...or uploaded files to the directory "myproject", then you should
## specify "/home/{my_name}/myproject"
path = '/home/{my_name}/bot'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
#

from main import app as application  # noqa

#
# NB -- many Flask guides suggest you use a file called run.py; that's
# not necessary on PythonAnywhere.  And you should make sure your code
# does *not* invoke the flask development server with app.run(), as it
# will prevent your wsgi file from working.`
```

Comment: Could you paste relevant part of your wsgi file and paths to files?

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for reaching out. I'm not sure which part of the wsgi file is relevant, but hope the part I added to my initial question will work.

Comment: What is the path to main and how is  imported_object imported and what is path to imported_object?

Comment: path to main: _home/{my_name}/bot/main.py_;
path to imported_object: _home/{my_name}/bot/{imported_object}.py_;
how imported object is imported:

_from {imported_object} import *_

Comment: The problem is not that the import is failing. The problem is that you have a file where you're using imported_object, but you have not imported it. The rest of the exception will indicate the file where that is happening.

Comment: @Glenn, I know where that is happening. And this file does import the imported_object correctly (= the code includes import command). And everything works perfectly on my computer. The problems start when I upload all the files to PythonAnywhere. I guess import is failing though. I just cannot figure out why.